# Why IIS 8.5 not showing personal certificates

Tags: iis, ssl

I followed this tut to add a self service certificate for testing my website,
http://www.jayway.com/2014/09/03/creating-self-signed-certificates-with-makecert-exe-for-development/

When I go to MMC console, In personal > Certificates

I can see my certificate, but when I go to IIS Manager then "Server Certificates" I don't see it there.

Any idea how can I add it ? when I try to import it, it asks for network key which I am not sure what is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it, in IIS 8.5 all you have to do is go to IIS Manager and then Server Certificates and then on empty space right click.

It will ask you to create self signed certificate, give it the name you want and click on finish. It should work as it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question has already been answered but I am adding this in case anyone is having the same issue and is forced to use a certificate which has been generated already.

In order to have it available in the IIS, you have to import the .pfx file in the Personal store or in the Web Hosting store ([for scaling purposes](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability)).